# Xcode 9 Beta - editor, column selection gone?

Tags: editor, xcode9-beta

In previous versions of Xcode, we could hold down Alt/Option key, drag the mouse to select columns in the text editor. In Xcode 9 Beta this doesn't seem to work.

Is this gone now, or is it a different key combination? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Xcode 9 release notes it is a missing feature.  I can only assume it will be added back in before the official release.

From the Xcode 9 [Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/WWDC_2017/Xcode_9_beta/Xcode_9_beta_Release_Notes.pdf) (page 21):

> Xcode 9’s new source editor does not yet support discontiguous or columnar selection. (30738532)

Comment: Fixed in Beta 4